# r: replace_na() not replacing NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, magrittr

I have a variable with NAs called `df$salesContribution`.

Using `dplyr` I've created a statement below, but can't figure out why my `df$salesContribution` is returning NAs still:

```
df<- df %>% 
  mutate(salesContribution = as.numeric(salesContribution)) %>% 
  replace_na(0)
```

Is the `0` not registering?

Comment: Please check the `str(df)` and also with `sum(is.na(df$salesContribution))` to find the total number of NA elements.  May be you have a character string as `"NA"`

Answer (score 2):

replace_na() will not work if the variable is a factor, and the replacement is not already a level for your factor.  If this is the issue, you can add another level to your factor variable for 0 before running replace_na(), or you can convert the variable to numeric or character first.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want

```
df$salesContribution <- df$salesContribution %>% as.numeric() %>% replace_na(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a blog response elsewhere in which Hadley himself said they wanted to move away from replace_na toward a more SQL adjacent command coalesce(). The solution involves both across and coalesce.
In my case, I used a different variable from the dataframe to supply the missing values ad hoc. You can also specify a fixed value.

Here's an example of what I just did in my work:

|  | Varname1 | Varname2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | Yes |
| 2 | NA | No |
| 3 | NA | Yes |
| 4 | No | No |

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(Varname1, coalesce, Varname2))
```

|  | Varname1 | Varname2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | Yes |
| 2 | No | No |
| 3 | Yes | Yes |
| 4 | No | No |

Answer (score 0):

You can do using base `replace`:

```
df<- df %>% 
  mutate(salesContribution = replace(as.numeric(salesContribution), which(is.na(salesContribution)), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If using `data.table` package you could do something like: You could try something like:
`x[is.na(field_name)][, field_name := replacement_value]`

There should be similar syntax for data.frame as well.